# Import csv walk through column 1 and modify each entry and add to Column 2

Tags: powershell

Here is what I am trying to achieve.

Import list of Usernames then convert them to generic password in a certain format.

this is what I have so far, but I know its not a 1:1 replace always. So, I am just stuck at what to do next.

```
        #Import List of Usernames from Already Generated .CSV File
        $Userlist = Import-Csv "Mycsvfile.csv"



        $Userlist | ForEach-Object {
        #Calls first column labled Username and Modifies first 2 letters.


        }
        Write-Output $userlist
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Is saving the list to column 2 the problem?

Comment: Sorry, no issue is going through the list and converting each Unique username and converting to a password. So for each Username for example MD19830 I would need to convert it to this format, MD1!(*#) . Where the the numbers in the user name represent the shifted values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an array or string of the 'shifted' values, and index into it.  Something like:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
        $shifted = ')!"£$%^&*('
        ########### 0123456789

        $nums = $_.username.Substring(2).ToCharArray()
        $pwd  = "Md"
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $nums.Length; $i++) {
            $n = [Convert]::ToInt32($nums[$i].ToString())
            $pwd += $shifted[$n]
        }
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Username=$_.username; Password=$pwd }
    }
```

Technically, `$shifted` can be defined above the loop, if it matters.  But remember that not everyone's shifted number values are the same, depending on keyboard layout.

Also, a list of usernames and passwords are never particularly secure.

Neither are easily derivable passwords.